# Preserve custom attributes when pickling subclass of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I've created a subclass of numpy ndarray following [the numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).  In particular, I have [added a custom attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray) by modifying the code provided.

I'm manipulating instances of this class within a parallel loop, using Python `multiprocessing`.  As I understand it, the way that the scope is essentially 'copied' to multiple threads is using `pickle`.

The problem I am now coming up against relates to the way that numpy arrays are pickled.  I can't find any comprehensive documentation about this, but some [discussions between the dill developers](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/48) suggest that I should be focusing on the `__reduce__` method, which is being called upon pickling.

Can anyone shed any more light on this?  The minimal working example is really just the numpy example code I linked to above, copied here for completeness:

```
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj.info = info
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

Now here is the problem:

```
import pickle

obj = RealisticInfoArray([1, 2, 3], info='foo')
print obj.info  # 'foo'

pickle_str = pickle.dumps(obj)
new_obj = pickle.loads(pickle_str)
print new_obj.info  #  raises AttributeError
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`np.ndarray` uses `__reduce__` to pickle itself. We can take a look at what it actually returns when you call that function to get an idea of what's going on:

```
>>> obj = RealisticInfoArray([1, 2, 3], info='foo')
>>> obj.__reduce__()
(<built-in function _reconstruct>, (<class 'pick.RealisticInfoArray'>, (0,), 'b'), (1, (3,), dtype('int64'), False, '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
```

So, we get a 3-tuple back. The docs for [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) describe what each element is doing:

> When a tuple is returned, it must be between two and five elements
>   long. Optional elements can either be omitted, or None can be provided
>   as their value. The contents of this tuple are pickled as normal and
>   used to reconstruct the object at unpickling time. The semantics of
>   each element are:
>
> - A callable object that will be called to create the initial version of
>     the object. The next element of the tuple will provide arguments for
>     this callable, and later elements provide additional state information
>     that will subsequently be used to fully reconstruct the pickled data.
>
>   In the unpickling environment this object must be either a class, a
>     callable registered as a “safe constructor” (see below), or it must
>     have an attribute `__safe_for_unpickling__` with a true value.
>     Otherwise, an `UnpicklingError` will be raised in the unpickling
>     environment. Note that as usual, the callable itself is pickled by
>     name.
> - A tuple of arguments for the callable object.
> - Optionally, the object’s state, which will be passed to the object’s
>     `__setstate__()` method as described in section Pickling and unpickling normal class instances. If the object has no `__setstate__()` method,
>     then, as above, the value must be a dictionary and it will be added to
>     the object’s `__dict__`.

So, `_reconstruct` is the function called to rebuild the object, `(<class 'pick.RealisticInfoArray'>, (0,), 'b')` are the arguments passed to that function, and `(1, (3,), dtype('int64'), False, '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))` gets passed to the class' `__setstate__`. This gives us an opportunity; we could override `__reduce__` and provide our own tuple to `__setstate__`, and then additionally override `__setstate__`, to set our custom attribute when we unpickle. We just need to make sure we preserve all the data the parent class needs, and call the parent's `__setstate__`, too:

```
class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def __reduce__(self):
        # Get the parent's __reduce__ tuple
        pickled_state = super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__reduce__()
        # Create our own tuple to pass to __setstate__
        new_state = pickled_state[2] + (self.info,)
        # Return a tuple that replaces the parent's __setstate__ tuple with our own
        return (pickled_state[0], pickled_state[1], new_state)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.info = state[-1]  # Set the info attribute
        # Call the parent's __setstate__ with the other tuple elements.
        super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__setstate__(state[0:-1])
```

Usage:

```
>>> obj = pick.RealisticInfoArray([1, 2, 3], info='foo')
>>> pickle_str = pickle.dumps(obj)
>>> pickle_str
"cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cpick\nRealisticInfoArray\np1\n(I0\ntp2\nS'b'\np3\ntp4\nRp5\n(I1\n(I3\ntp6\ncnumpy\ndtype\np7\n(S'i8'\np8\nI0\nI1\ntp9\nRp10\n(I3\nS'<'\np11\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp12\nbI00\nS'\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\np13\nS'foo'\np14\ntp15\nb."
>>> new_obj = pickle.loads(pickle_str)
>>> new_obj.info
'foo'
```

Comment: Great, that has fixed it.  Thank you also for the very clear code example.  I'm actually transferring across the `__dict__` object to make this more generic.  Fortunately np.ndarray doesn't *seem* to use it, so I'm free to use it for my own purposes.

Answer (score 8):

I'm the `dill` (and `pathos`) author.  `dill` was pickling a `numpy.array` before `numpy` could do it itself.  @dano's explanation is pretty accurate.  Me personally, I'd just use `dill` and let it do the job for you.  With `dill`, you don't need `__reduce__`, as `dill` has several ways that it grabs subclassed attributes… one of which is storing the `__dict__` for any class object.  `pickle` doesn't do this, b/c it usually works with classes by name reference and not storing the class object itself… so you have to work with `__reduce__` to make `pickle` work for you.  No need, in most cases, with `dill`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
...     def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
...         # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
...         # We first cast to be our class type
...         obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
...         # add the new attribute to the created instance
...         obj.info = info
...         # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
...         return obj
...     def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
...         # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
...         if obj is None: return
...         self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
... 
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> obj = RealisticInfoArray([1, 2, 3], info='foo')
>>> print obj.info  # 'foo'
foo
>>> 
>>> pickle_str = pickle.dumps(obj)
>>> new_obj = pickle.loads(pickle_str)
>>> print new_obj.info
foo
```

`dill` can extend itself into `pickle` (essentially by `copy_reg` everything it knows), so you can then use all `dill` types in anything that uses `pickle`.  Now, if you are going to use `multiprocessing`, you are a bit screwed, since it uses `cPickle`.  There is, however, the `pathos` fork of `multiprocessing` (called `pathos.multiprocessing`), which basically the only change is it uses `dill` instead of `cPickle`… and thus can serialize a heck of a lot more in a `Pool.map`.  I think (currently) if you want to work with your subclass of a `numpy.array` in `multiprocessing` (or `pathos.multiprocessing`), you might have to do something like @dano suggests -- but not sure, as I didn't think of a good case off the top of my head to test your subclass.

If you are interested, get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you very much.  Only reason I didn't accept this one is because @dano's suggestion works without switching packages.  FWIW, I agree that dill is always preferable to pickle and will strongly consider checking out pathos in the future.

Comment: Gabriel, In this case, I would have also taken @dano's answer over mine, but I figured the more information for you the better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight improvement to @dano's answer and and @Gabriel's comment. Leveraging the `__dict__` attribute for serialization works for me even with subclasses.

```
def __reduce__(self):
    # Get the parent's __reduce__ tuple
    pickled_state = super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__reduce__()
    # Create our own tuple to pass to __setstate__, but append the __dict__ rather than individual members.
    new_state = pickled_state[2] + (self.__dict__,)
    # Return a tuple that replaces the parent's __setstate__ tuple with our own
    return (pickled_state[0], pickled_state[1], new_state)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state[-1])  # Update the internal dict from state
    # Call the parent's __setstate__ with the other tuple elements.
    super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__setstate__(state[0:-1])
```

Here is a full example: https://onlinegdb.com/SJ88d5DLB