# How can I make np.save work for an ndarray subclass?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to be able to save my array subclass to a npy file, and recover the result later.

Something like:

```
>>> class MyArray(np.ndarray): pass
>>> data = MyArray(np.arange(10))
>>> np.save('fname', data)
>>> data2 = np.load('fname')
>>> assert isinstance(data2, MyArray)  # raises AssertionError
```

[the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html#requirements) says (emphasis mine):

> The format explicitly does not need to:
>
> - [...]
> - Fully handle arbitrary subclasses of numpy.ndarray. Subclasses will be
>     accepted for writing, but only the array data will be written out. A
>     regular numpy.ndarray object will be created upon reading the file.
>     **The API can be used to build a format for a particular subclass**, but
>     that is out of scope for the general NPY format.

So is it possible to make the above code not raise an AssertionError?

Comment: Are you asking how to store data in the `npy` file so that numpy knows to user your subclass when reading the data back in (via numpy.load)?  Is a solution where you use [view casting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#view-casting) _after_ reading the data as a vanilla numpy array OK?

Comment: @mgilson: View casting is not quite. I'd like the file to encode what class it should be viewed as, not the programmer. Also, ideally I'd be able to store some metadata of my own corresponding to properties on my class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see evidence that `np.save` handles array subclasses.

I tried to save a `np.matrix` with it, and got back a `ndarray`.

I tried to save a `np.ma` array, and got an error

```
NotImplementedError: MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet.
```

Saving is done by `np.lib.npyio.format.write_array`, which does

```
_write_array_header()   # save dtype, shape etc
```

if `dtype` is object it uses `pickle.dump(array, fp ...)`

otherwise it does  `array.tofile(fp)`.  `tofile` handles writing the data buffer.

I think `pickle.dump` of an array ends up using `np.save`, but I don't recall how that's triggered.

I can for example `pickle` an array, and load it:

```
In [657]: f=open('test','wb')
In [658]: pickle.Pickler(f).dump(x)
In [659]: f.close()
In [660]: np.load('test')
In [664]: f=open('test','rb')
In [665]: pickle.load(f)
```

This `pickle` dump/load sequence works for test `np.ma`, `np.matrix` and `sparse.coo_matrix` cases.  So that's probably the direction to explore for your own subclass.

Searching on `numpy` and `pickle` I found [Preserve custom attributes when pickling subclass of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26598109/901925).  The answer involves a custom `.__reduce__` and `.__setstate__`.