# numpy array flags information is not saved when dumping to pickle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

I'm writing a class that has an attribute of numpy array type.
Since I'd like it to be read-only, I set its WRITABLE flag to be false:

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_array = np.zeros(5)
        self.my_array.setflags(write=False)
```

After doing some other stuff, I dump MyClass into a pickle file:

```
pickle.dump(self, writer)
```

Later, I load it using `x = pickle.load(reader)`, but then the WRITABLE flag is true.
How can I make the pickle dump to preserve the numpy array WRITABLE flag?

Comment: Your constructor only runs when you create an instance of your object. How did you find out that it didn't set the flag?

Comment: It's not surprising that the flags aren't preserved, considering that most of them represent properties that wouldn't be preserved by the pickling/unpickling process. For example, C_CONTIGUOUS and OWNDATA.

Answer (score 0):

For pickling arrays, numpy uses the `np.save` function.  Details of this save are in `np.lib.format` file.  This format saves a header and a byte representation of the data buffer.  The content of header is a dictionary.

```
In [1212]: np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(x)
Out[1212]: {'descr': '<i4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (2, 3)}
In [1213]: np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(u)
Out[1213]: {'descr': '<c16', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (4,)}
```

As you can see it does not save the whole `FLAGS` attribute, just info on the order.

Class pickling can be customized with `__reduce__` and `__setstate__` methods.

See also

[How can I make np.save work for an ndarray subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839174/how-can-i-make-np-save-work-for-an-ndarray-subclass)