# subclassing ndarray drops information when broadcast in pyspark

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I'm hoping someone can help me debug an issue we're seeing with subclassed `ndarray`s in spark. Specifically when [broadcast](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jegonzal/pyspark/_modules/pyspark/broadcast.html) a subclassed array it seems to lose the extra information. A trivial example is below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> class Test(np.ndarray):
...     def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
...         obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
...         obj.info = info
...         return obj
...     
...     def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
...         if not hasattr(self, "info"):
...             self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
...         else:
...             print("has info attribute: %s" % getattr(self, 'info'))
... 
>>> test = Test(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), info="info")
>>> print(test.info)
info
>>> print(sc.broadcast(test).value)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
>>> print(sc.broadcast(test).value.info)
None
```

Comment: This thread solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598109/preserve-custom-attributes-when-pickling-subclass-of-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you have a small typo - you're checking for `hasattr(obj, "info")` when instead you should be checking `if hasattr(self, "info")`.  Because of the if statement flip, info isn't being carried over.

```
test = Test(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), info="info")
print test.info # info
test2 = test[1:]
print test2.info # info
```

Comment: good catch! doesn't fix the overarching issue though :(