# multiprocessing.Pool.map() drops attribute of subclassed ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, subclass, python-multiprocessing

When using `map()` from `multiprocessing.Pool()` on a list of instances from a `numpy.ndarray`-subclass, the new attributes of the own class are dropped.

The following minimal example based on the [numpy docs subclassing example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) reproduces the problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


class MyArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

def sum_worker(x):
    return sum(x) , x.info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr_list = [MyArray(np.random.rand(3), info=f'foo_{i}') for i in range(10)]
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(sum_worker, arr_list)
```

The attribute `info` is dropped

```
AttributeError: 'MyArray' object has no attribute 'info'
```

Using the builtin `map()` works fine

```
arr_list = [MyArray(np.random.rand(3), info=f'foo_{i}') for i in range(10)]
list(map(sum_worker, arr_list2))
```

The purpose of the method `__array_finalize__()` is that the object keeps the attribute after slicing

```
arr = MyArray([1,2,3], info='foo')
subarr = arr[:2]
print(subarr.info)
```

But for `Pool.map()` this method is somehow not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because multiprocessing uses `pickle` to serialize data to/from separate processes, this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598109/preserve-custom-attributes-when-pickling-subclass-of-numpy-array).

Adapting the accepted solution from that question, your example becomes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def __reduce__(self):
        pickled_state = super(MyArray, self).__reduce__()
        new_state = pickled_state[2] + (self.info,)
        return (pickled_state[0], pickled_state[1], new_state)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.info = state[-1]
        super(MyArray, self).__setstate__(state[0:-1])

def sum_worker(x):
    return sum(x) , x.info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr_list = [MyArray(np.random.rand(3), info=f'foo_{i}') for i in range(10)]
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(sum_worker, arr_list)
```

Note, the second answer suggests you might be able to use `pathos.multiprocessing` with your unadapted original code since pathos uses `dill` instead of `pickle`. This did not work when I tested it however.