# How to pickle numpy ndarray derived class?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, pickle

I pickled an instance of a class derived from ndarray, but lose the attributes during pickling/unpickling.  Below is simplified code to illustrate the problem.  I don't understand:

1. Why isn't "attrib" included in pickle dump/load?  What do I have to do so that it is included?
2. Why isn't __getstate__() called during dump so that I can add the missing "atrrib"?  __setstate__() was called.  How was the state gotten to be set?  My thought was that I would add "attrib" to the gotten state so that I could later set it.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

class Xndarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, (5, 3), **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self[...] = -1
        self.attrib = 0

    def add2getstate(self):
        print("add2getstate()", self.__dict__)   

    def __getstate__(self):                         # This never gets called
        print("__getstate__()")
        return super().__getstate__()

    def __setstate__(self, data):
        print("__setstate__()")
        super().__setstate__(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fname = "fname.pkl"

    x = Xndarray()

    x[0] = 0
    x.attrib += 2

    print(x)
    x.add2getstate()
    print(x.attrib)

    with open(fname, "wb") as fh:
        pickle.dump(x, fh)

    print("---------------")

    with open(fname, "rb") as fh:
        y = pickle.load(fh)

    print(y)
    y.add2getstate()
    print(y.attrib)
```

Here is the output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]]
add2getstate() {'attrib': 2}
2
---------------
__setstate__()
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]]
add2getstate() {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(y.attrib)
AttributeError: 'Xndarray' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Comment: I have additional attributes related to the numpy arrays that I wish to save with the numpy arrays.  Additionally, the numpy arrays are part of a larger data structure that is serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays do not implement __getstate__ but __reduce__ .

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types

Comment: Thank you (and also to user2357112).  I was able to get my code to work using \_\_reduce\_\_ and changing \_\_setstate\_\_.  When I did a search for \_\_reduce\_\_ examples, I found my question already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598109/preserve-custom-attributes-when-pickling-subclass-of-numpy-array.

Answer (score 3):

`__getstate__` is only called if your object uses the default `__reduce__`/`__reduce_ex__`. `numpy.ndarray` has its own `__reduce__` implementation that does not call your `__getstate__`.

`numpy.ndarray.__reduce__` only includes the object data it knows about, not `self.attrib`, and `numpy.ndarray.__setstate__` would not know how to set `self.attrib` even if you included that attribute somehow.

You will need to implement your own `__reduce__` and `__setstate__` and handle `self.attrib` yourself.

Comment: That's what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you implemented `__getstate__`at all.
Try to remove `__getstate__` and then it should be complete.

There's no `self.attrib`in the pickle, because you implement you own `__getstate__` and return just the `__getstate__` from the class you inherit.

Comment: I implemented __getstate__ to demonstrate that it was not called during pickle dump.  Removing it has no impact on the output.

Comment: Please try this somewhere and show the output `print(super().__getstate__())`

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./np_pkl_tst.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(x.pr())
  File "./np_pkl_tst.py", line 18, in pr
    print(super().__getstate__())
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getstate__'```

Comment: Yeah the return is definitive `False`. This is from python docs: "If __getstate__() returns a false value, the __setstate__() method will not be called upon unpickling."

Answer (score 0):

Use dill instead of pickle  https://pypi.org/project/dill/ . As dill extends from pickle the interface pretty much is the same.

```
import dill
with open(fname, "wb") as fh:
    dill.dump(x,fh)

print("---------------")

with open(fname, "rb") as fh:
    y = dill.load(fh)
```

Comment: Using dill got my posted test case to work.  It didn't work on my full project where I have an instance of the subclassed numpy object assigned to an attribute in a second object, where the second object is pickled.  To get that to work I had to use \_\_reduce\_\_ and \_\_setstate\_\_.