# Saving subclass of numpy ndarray after storing it on disk

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

Suppose I have an `array` that is an instance of subclassed from `np.ndarray` class:

```
class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def __reduce__(self):
        print('in reduce')
        # Get the parent's __reduce__ tuple
        pickled_state = super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__reduce__()
        # Create our own tuple to pass to __setstate__
        new_state = pickled_state[2] + (self.info,)
        # Return a tuple that replaces the parent's __setstate__ tuple with our own
        return (pickled_state[0], pickled_state[1], new_state)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print('in set_state')
        self.info = state[-1]  # Set the info attribute
        # Call the parent's __setstate__ with the other tuple elements.
        super(RealisticInfoArray, self).__setstate__(state[0:-1])
        
    def tofile(self, fid, sep="", format="%s"):
        super().tofile(fid, sep, format)
        print('in tofile')
        
    def tobytes(self, order='C'):
        super().tobytes(order)
        print('in tobytes')

array = RealisticInfoArray(np.zeros((7, 9, 13)), info='tester')
```

Methods `__reduce__`, `__setstate__`, `tofile` and `tobytes` are included because I think they are involved in the saving that I want to perform: I want to store the array on disk (via any of the `np.save`, `np.savez`, `np.savez_compressed`) and load it back while preserving the class of that object and all of the custom attributes.

I've already tried the approach of [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598109/preserve-custom-attributes-when-pickling-subclass-of-numpy-array), but that is not working because I want to use `np` functions, not `pickle` or `dill`. Also, I borrowed the subclass for MWE from there.

Another bit of information is that the actual saving is performed by `np.lib.npyio.format.write_array`, which does not seem to allow any custom behavior of storing the data.

So, my question is whether it is possible to preserve the class of a stored array and if yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What do existing subclasses do?  `np.matrix`, `np.recarray` and `np.ma.MaskedArray`.    I have not tested their `save` or looked to see if they have special code.  `matrix` has the same attributes and data buffer, just methods that restrict dimensions.  Masked array has both `data` and `mask` array attributes.  `recarray` is like a structured array with a different indexing method.

`scipy.sparse` has its own save, which uses `savez` to save its own attributes.  That requires its own load too, to recreate the matrix.  `sparse` though is not a subclass.

I may do some exploring myself later.

But don't turn up your nose at `pickle`.  There's a close connection between `np.save` and `pickle`.  `np.save` is the pickle method for `ndarray`,while `save` uses `pickle` to serialize object elements.

Matrix subclass is not preserved:

```
In [52]: np.save('matrix.npy',M)
In [53]: np.load('matrix.npy')
Out[53]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`pickle` preserves the subclass (demo omitted).

`np.save` isn't implemented for masked arrays:

```
In [66]: ma = np.ma.masked_array(np.ones(4))
In [67]: ma
Out[67]: 
masked_array(data=[1., 1., 1., 1.],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20)
In [68]: np.save('masked.npy',ma)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-68-3c39e0b0fc22>", line 1, in <module>
    np.save('masked.npy',ma)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in save
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 529, in save
    pickle_kwargs=dict(fix_imports=fix_imports))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 675, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 6116, in tofile
    raise NotImplementedError("MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet.")
NotImplementedError: MaskedArray.tofile() not implemented yet.
```

Again pickle works:

```
In [69]: with open('masked.pkl','wb') as f:
    ...:     pickle.dump(ma,f)
    ...: 
In [70]: with open('masked.pkl','rb') as f:
    ...:     pp=pickle.load(f)
    ...: 
In [71]: pp
Out[71]: 
masked_array(data=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
             mask=[False, False, False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```